# extracting data using beautifulsoup

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

#specify the url
wiki = "http://www.bbc.com/urdu"

#Query the website and return the html to the variable 'page'
page = urlopen(wiki)


#Parse the html in the 'page' variable, and store it in Beautiful Soup format
soup = BeautifulSoup(page,"html.parser")
all_links=soup.find_all("a")
for link in all_links:
    #print (link.get("href"))
    #text=soup.body.get_text()
    #print(text)
    for script in soup(["script", "style"]):
        script.extract()    # rip it out

# get text
text=soup.body.get_text()

# break into lines and remove leading and trailing space on each
lines = (line.strip() for line in text.splitlines())
# break multi-headlines into a line each
chunks = (phrase.strip() for line in lines for phrase in line.split("  "))
# drop blank lines
text = '\n'.join(chunk for chunk in chunks if chunk)

print(text)
text1 = str(text) 
text_file = open("C:\\Output.txt", 'w') 
text_file.write(text) 
text_file.close()
```

I want to extract data from a news website using beautiful soup. I wrote a code, but it is not giving me the required output. Firstly, I have to process all the links in a page and then extract data from that and save it to a file. Then, more on to next page and extract data and save it and so on… Right now, I was just trying to process links on first page, but it is not giving me the full text and also it is giving me some tags in output.

Answer (score 0):

To extract all links from a website you can try something like this:

```
data = []
soup = BeautifulSoup(page,"html.parser")
for link in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
    data.append(link['href'])

text = '\n'.join(data)
print(text)
```

And then proceed to save text into a file. After this you need to iterate over `data` to get all the urls for those websites aswell.

Comment: thank you for replying but this will just extract the links.i want to extract text from all those links.